# Scroll textfield up when keyboard popsup

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am using html5/javascript/jQuery/css for mobile app development. I have multiple textareas in the app. When I click on that to input, keyboard popup (android tab). But the textarea stays where it's on that page. How can I scroll page when keyboard pops up.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API This helps in showing the changes done on the visual viewport. You can check for height and update accordingly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

with jQuery, get the textarea's [`offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) value then set document scroll position using [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
var $htmlOrBody = $('html, body'), // scrollTop works on <body> for some browsers, <html> for others
    scrollTopPadding = 8;

$('textarea').focus(function() {
    // get textarea's offset top position
    var textareaTop = $(this).offset().top;
    // scroll to the textarea
    $htmlOrBody.scrollTop(textareaTop - scrollTopPadding);
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AuVRD/1/)

Answer (score 4):

To complete the answer, if you want to animate the scroll replace:

```
$htmlOrBody.scrollTop(textareaTop - scrollTopPadding);
```

by

```
var timing = 250;
$htmlOrBody.animate({ scrollTop: textareaTop - scrollTopPadding }, timing);
```

Answer (score 0):

just detect browser window size change, when keyboard pops up, the browser window size will change

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $htmlOrBody = $('html, body'), // scrollTop works on <body> for some browsers, <html> for others
    scrollTopPadding = 8;
    // get input tag's offset top position
    var textareaTop = $(this).offset().top;
    // scroll to the textarea
    $htmlOrBody.scrollTop(textareaTop - scrollTopPadding);

    // OR  To add animation for smooth scrolling, use this. 
    //$htmlOrBody.animate({ scrollTop: textareaTop - scrollTopPadding }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method:

```
let inputs = $('input[type=text], textarea');
inputs.focus(function() {
    $(this)[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```